# Server not responding after LetsEncrypt SSL install

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vps

I am pushing my website to AWS Lightsail instance on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have had trouble accessing it since I installed LetsEncrypt (everything was fine beforehand).

Basically, I am getting no response, although it looks like everything is fine, at least to me. My website is called kolibri.ba, and I installed 2 SSL's for both [www.kolibri.ba](http://www.kolibri.ba) and kolibri.ba. I tried different UFW settings, turning it off totally and so on.

My Virtual Host (kolibri.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName kolibri.ba
        ServerAlias www.kolibri.ba

        ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_mysite.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_access_mysite.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =kolibri.ba [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.kolibri.ba
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Searching "kolibri" everywhere inside /etc/apache2 looks like this

````
ack "kolibri" /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/kolibri.conf
4:  ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba  
5:  ServerName  kolibri.ba    
6:  ServerAlias www.kolibri.ba
16:  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-kolibri.ba.log
17:  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-kolibri.ba.log combined

/etc/apache2/sites-available/kolibri.conf
2:        ServerName kolibri.ba
3:        ServerAlias www.kolibri.ba
5:        ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba
12:RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =kolibri.ba [OR]
13:RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.kolibri.ba

/etc/apache2/sites-available/kolibri-2-le-ssl.conf
3:    ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba
4:    ServerName kolibri.ba
5:    ServerAlias www.kolibri.ba
11:#SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kolibri.ba/fullchain.pem
12:#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kolibri.ba/privkey.pem

/etc/apache2/sites-available/kolibri-le-ssl.conf
3:        ServerName www.kolibri.ba
4:        ServerAlias kolibri.ba
6:        ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba
14:SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/kolibri.ba/fullchain.pem
15:SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/kolibri.ba/privkey.pem
20:        ServerName kolibri.ba
21:        ServerAlias www.kolibri.ba
23:        ServerAdmin kontakt@kolibri.ba
33:# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =kolibri.ba [OR]
34:# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.kolibri.ba```

I added these lines to my wp-config.php as well
````

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://kolibri.ba' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://kolibri.ba' );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true)```

Firewall settings looks like this

```
 sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
30000:31000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20:21/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
30000:31000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20:21/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

If I do nmap 443 and 80 ports locally to my domain, it gives this

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp  open     http
443/tcp filtered https
```

Not sure if 443 filtered state could be causing the issue or what?

And as last, I am putting here my apache health stats:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-0-121:~$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-20 20:56:26 CEST; 11min ago
  Process: 5339 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5300 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5344 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5358 (apache2)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 2362)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─5358 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5363 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5364 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5365 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5366 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5367 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5382 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─5385 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─5386 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 20 20:56:26 ip-172-26-0-121 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 20 20:56:26 ip-172-26-0-121 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 20 20:56:26 ip-172-26-0-121 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I spent 2 days debugging this, and I would kill my instance 15 times so far if WordPress wasn't such a pain to import properly. Please help and thanks a lot!

Comment: I have further concerns, SSL is part of security but that UFW is scary! I could run a ripper on the SSH all sorts. Have you gone through the steps to properly secure your server?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Configure things correctly and this should work you don't need all the virtualhosts just one. When complete restart the services but if the SSL is wrong it will fail.